# What is happening at the end of the Another manga?

Tags: another

I've just finished the Another manga and I don't really understand the final 2 pages.

What are the clanging noises, and who is the mysterious figure in the hallway?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well from my understanding of the anime, the Calamity is only stopped for that year. It will occur again, so the figure could be who will become the next Extra in the class.

Apart from that, my only other basis is the top left frame, if the seating positions are the same in the manga then figure where is sitting in Mei's seat which the class uses as a counter measure to make someone non existent and, I think it is also the same seat of the first student who died, but was allowed to graduate which caused the Calamity to begin the year after.

of course take this with a grain of salt since

> the anime ends with 2 people of the class re-recording the message in how to stop the calamity as a means to prevent the insanity that engulfed the class when the original recording was made public

i've no idea how different the anime is from the manga or the Light Novel

Answer (score 1):

It could also be **Misaki, the student who was forever stuck in Yomiyama.**

*From the [Wiki](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Misaki_Yomiyama#Manga):*

> Misaki's final appearance in the manga was in the final chapter, walking around the school, suggesting he is still stuck on earth.

Meaning that he is the reason that the calamity would continue to occur, since he is trapped on earth.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a prequel to this in manga.
Before dying, Ritsuko (Kouichi's mother) saw the same shadow as this one and calls out 'Misaki-kun'.
So the shadow is in fact MISAKI.